# Sorting Machines based on the first month(Jan) by Efficiency in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

[image]

With reference to the image, I need to sort my Machines i.e SR1,SR2,SR3 by efficiency of the machines in descending order, but considering only January Month.

For Eg : 
SR1 : Jan Efficiency : 90.
SR2 : Jan Efficiency : 75.
SR3 : Jan Efficiency : 95.

So the correct sort way the machines should be sorted is  :
SR3 then SR1 then SR2.

Please suggest how can I do this in Tableau.

Tableau File can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_sG9WZOggf51SZHv_rjdK4moqY2OZ-QN) :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are likely many ways to accomplish. I would do a fixed level of detail calculation:

```
Jan Efficiency By Machine:
{ FIXED [Machine Name] : SUM(IIF([Month] = "January",[Efficiency %],NULL))}
```

Then put a sort on the Machine Name field that sorts by `Jan Efficiency By Machine` descending.

The field calculates the sum of [Efficiency %] for all rows where [Month] is "January" and NULL otherwise. The fixed part means it does the sum at the [Machine Name] level, regardless of what other dimensions are in the view. In a given view, every row with the same [Machine Name] will have the same [Jan Efficiency by Machine] value.

In this particular case, another way to accomplish the same thing is to create a field:

```
January Efficiency
IF [Month] = "January"
    THEN [Efficiency %]
ELSE
    NULL
END
```

(Drag that [January Efficiency] row to label to understand what it is doing).

Then order [Machine Name] by January Efficiency. Let's say aggregation is SUM (in this case it doesn't really matter what the aggregation is). The view then sums the [January Efficiency] values for a [Machine Name] (all but 1 are NULL) and sorts by that field.  Same basic thing happening with the level of detail--for each [Machine Name] "January Efficiency" gets summed (all but 1 are NULL).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked! However what are other ways to do it. Or simply if you could explain what you did there. I have struggled around LOD's
Thanks again.

Comment: I would read [LOD Overview](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html). I have edited the answer to explain better what the calculation is doing.

Comment: Thank You so much. I really appreciate your help.
could you please also explain if i can extend this sort to the Months. Eg : Units on Site will always be first followed by all the months in the ascending order. Like Jan followed by Feb,Mar,April so on